# Accidentally poured gas into antifreeze in tractor

Tags: engine, tractor

I was gonna fill our tractor with gas and there were to caps, a metal one a d a filter looking one, neither was labeled so I figured the metal cap was the gas cap, I put gas in it for just a few seconds an it exploded out, it was then drain in out a tube under the tractor. I think a lot of it came out and I left the cap off for awhile to let it evaporate hopefully, will it be fine?

Comment: Did you completely drain the coolant, then refill with fresh coolant? If you did that, you shouldn't have any issues. If you haven't, you'll want to, then you should be fine.

Comment: Nope, I've looked Down in there with a flashlight and I see the blue antifreeze and just s few spots of brown scum on top, idk how long its been since it been changed its an old tractor, idk really know how to drain it I'm 16 and dumb, and I guess I might have to tell my dad and he will prob have a fit 

Comment: I used it for a little after and it ran fine if that helps

Comment: Be up front with your Dad. Tell him you F-ed up. He may be a little upset, but he'll respect you a lot more for owning up to it.

Comment: I guess if that's wut I gotta do

Comment: You'll still probably want to flush the coolant, though. You might suggest that to your Pops.

Answer (score 2):

Gasoline is a fire hazard to the tractor, and can degrade rubber hoses and seals in the cooling system.

Do a complete flush and fill, as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Flush and refill as soon as you can as kmrash said.

I would also refill it with water right after draining it run it for a little then drain the water. After this add the new coolant.

To drain it there should be a valve at the bottom of the radiator. If you do not see one you can always remove the lower radiator hose from the, radiator not from the engine (radiator is usually the lowest point), and let it drain out that way. Again flush it with some regular water then refill with a proper mix of coolant for your climate.

Comment: wow I just realized this is really old.

Comment: It's OK. Stack Exchange rewards answering old questions for a reason, it becomes part of the site's knowledge base. This situation will occur to someone else at some point, and they'll find answers here.